# Drab a div's height in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently programming a custom dropdown component. right now, here's how the dropdown's height is determined:

```
maxHeight: dropDownOpen ? '600px' : '24px'
```

`dropDownOpen` is a state that tells me whether the dropdown is open. It uses that to toggle between the two heights mentioned above:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't actually scale down to 600px. That's because my `height` is set to `min-content`.

```
height: 'min-content'
```

I know to use 24px as the closed height because, in Chrome DevTools, it tells me the child div's height is 24px:

[image]

I also know that the opened height of the blue menu is 323.5px, and the red one is 203.5px, from looking at DevTools:

[image]
[image]

How could I grab this value within the function itself? The max-height going over also affects the speed of my animations, so I'd like them both to be accurate. Here's my code:

```
export default function JSelect({ options, primaryColor, textColor, width }: JSelectProps) {

const defaultValue = 4;

const [currentOption, setCurrentOption] = React.useState(defaultValue);

const [dropDownOpen, setDropDownOpen] = React.useState(false);


// Styles
const buttonstyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    width: width
};


const menustyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    backgroundColor: hoverState, //primaryColor
    color: textColor,
    height: 'min-content',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: '20px',
    padding: '5px 15px',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    transition: 'background-color 0.2s ease, max-height 0.5s ease',
    maxHeight: dropDownOpen ? '324px' : '24px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    userSelect: 'none'
};


function toggleDropDown(): void {
    setDropDownOpen(prev => !prev)
}

const optionElements: any = options.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div
            onClick={() => setCurrentOption(item.value)}
            onMouseEnter={() => makeThisHover(index)}
            style={{
                color: optionsHover[index] ? lightenColor(textColor) : textColor
            }}
        >{item.label}</div>)
})

return (
    <div style={menustyle}
        onMouseEnter={onHover}
        onMouseLeave={onHoverExit}
        onClick={toggleDropDown}

    >
        <div
            style={buttonstyle}
        >
            {options[options.findIndex(item => item.value === currentOption)].label}
            <div style={{ // Maybe make it a hollow triangle with rounded edges?
                height: '15px',
                display: 'flex',
                transform: dropDownOpen ? '' : 'rotate(-180deg)',
                transition: 'transform 250ms ease',
                marginLeft: 'auto'
            }}>
                <DropDownArrow fill="currentColor" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style={{ height: '1.5px', backgroundColor: textColor, margin: '5px 0px' }} />
        <div>
            {optionElements}
        </div>

    </div>
);
```

Comment: within which function? - please add a [mre] to your question

Comment: once the div is open and sized, [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) should work just fine. But the question is _why_ you need those values: are to make the CSS transition animation be based on content height rather than time? Because you know how many lines of content are in each menu (because you have the data used to generate those lines) so you can just pick a "time per line" and get perfectly fine animations without needing to know exact pixel values.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If the bounding box's height is 600px (like the current example), but the container is actually ~300px, then the animation will finish at it's half way point. That means that the ease-in-out will suddenly stop halfway, instead of sliding into it's finish. The animation doesn't look smooth and the time is inconsistent.

I need those values so that the animation actually uses the correct amount of time, and looks smooth. If I could grab those values, my code would look like this:
maxHeight: dropDownOpen ? divHeightWhenDropIsOpen : divHeightWhenDropIsClosed

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I also don't like the idea of hard-coding 24px as the closed height, because what if the label takes up two rows? I want this component to be reusable, so I don't want to do that

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I will try that solution though and see if I can implement it that way